# How to delay an item in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

I have repeating items that I would like to do every day but sometimes miss, e.g.:

```
** TODO That nasty habit
SCHEDULED: <2019-09-28 Sat 06:00 ++1d>
:PROPERTIES:...
:LOGBOOK:...
```

I can move point to the timestamp after `SCHEDULED` and do `S-RIGHT`, which shifts to the next day.

I could not find a relevant function `M-x org-*delay`, nor `M-x org-*schedule`.

How can I delay the item, while keeping the time and the repetition cookie, ideally with a key binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Delaying by one or multiple days

Here is a function inspired by `org-shiftright`, the function bound to the key `S-RIGHT` (find it with `C-h k S-RIGHT`), which on a timestamp calls `org-timestamp-up-day`, which itself calls `org-timestamp-change`. It binds the function to `C-c d`. Place this in your init file, such as `~/.emacs`:

```el
(defun org-delay-scheduled (&optional n)
  "Delay the headline at point by the number of days, keeping the time and repetition cookie."
  (interactive)
  ;; Raise error if entry lacks SCHEDULED, or whatever the value of org-scheduled-string
  ;; except for the colon
  (let ((scheduled-string (car (split-string org-scheduled-string ":"))))
    (unless (org-entry-get nil scheduled-string)
      (user-error (concat "This entry lacks a '" scheduled-string "' property")))
    (save-excursion
      (search-forward (concat org-scheduled-string " ")) ; move point to the scheduled entry
      (search-forward " ") ; move point inside the timestamp
      (org-timestamp-change (if n n 1) 'day nil))))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c d") 'org-delay-scheduled)
```

The result is:

```
** TODO That nasty habit
SCHEDULED: <2019-09-29 Sun 06:00 ++1d>
:PROPERTIES:...
:LOGBOOK:...
```

You can then call this function from another, e.g. if you want another key binding to delay by two weeks:

```el
(defun org-delay-scheduled-sprint ()
  "Delay the headline at point by the default of a sprint, 2 weeks."
  (interactive)
  (org-delay-scheduled 14))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c w") 'org-delay-scheduled-sprint)
```

### Delaying to present day first

The function above will delay by a fixed number of days. If you have an item far in the past the result may still be in the past, unlike the behavior of `S-RIGHT` on an entry with a repeating cookie, which first moves it to present. Here is a revision that first delays the entry to today, and then increments the fixed number of days. It uses a function that gets a slice of a list (from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108169/how-do-i-take-a-slice-of-a-list-a-sublist-in-scheme)), and does some juggling to get the number of days from the timestamp to today.

```el
(defun get-n-items (lst num)
  "Get the first num items from the list."
  (if (> num 0)
      (cons (car lst) (get-n-items (cdr lst) (- num 1)))
    '()))

(defun slice (lst start count)
  "Gets count elements from list starting at start."
  (if (> start 1)
      (slice (cdr lst) (- start 1) count)
    (get-n-items lst count)))

(defun org-delay-scheduled (&optional n)
  "Delay the headline at point by the number of days, keeping the time and repetition cookie."
  (interactive)
  ;; Raise error if entry lacks SCHEDULED, or whatever the value of org-scheduled-string
  ;; except for the colon
  (let ((scheduled-string (car (split-string org-scheduled-string ":"))))
    (unless (org-entry-get nil scheduled-string)
      (user-error (concat "This entry lacks a '" scheduled-string "' property")))
    (save-excursion
      (search-forward (concat org-scheduled-string " ")) ; move point to the scheduled entry
      (let* ((timestamp-string (buffer-substring (point) (line-end-position)))
         (timestamp-list (org-parse-time-string timestamp-string))
         (timestamp-start-of-day (append '(0 0 0) (slice timestamp-list 4 3)))
         (timestamp-internal (apply #'encode-time timestamp-start-of-day))
         (day-in-seconds (* 24 (* 60 60)))
         (days-to-present (truncate (/ (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) timestamp-internal)) day-in-seconds)))
         (days-to-delay (+ days-to-present (if n n 1))))
    (search-forward " ") ; move point inside the timestamp
    (org-timestamp-change days-to-delay 'day nil)))))

(defun org-delay-scheduled-sprint ()
  "Delay the headline at point by the default of a sprint, 2 weeks."
  (interactive)
  (org-delay-scheduled 14))
```